# Backspace in "JFileChoooser"

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I'm using `JFileChooser` in my project, and I have a problem like:

1 . Example, currently, I am at in folder like this image:

[image: 1]

I will access it and when I backspace or up to one level, I want to dialog of `JFileChooser` will show like that image (high line old folder selected).

2 . How to edit "Look in" like that in explore of windows.

Can you help me?

Comment: I'd start by having a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: I don't think you can do the (1) easily. You will have to change the JFileChooser implementation.

Comment: shan1024. Can you give me some example for it.